# How to capture focus-in on md-autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am using [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) and I am needing how to capture event Focus-In when my `md-autocomplete` got focus.

Besides focus-in, my good need is clear the option selected.

How do I do this?